# Select the latest version based on date for each ID in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max, distinct, mysql-num-rows

I have a table like:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| listing_id | transaction_title | image_thumb  | sale_date  |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 226835186  | Title Version 11  | Img Style 11 | 2016-02-08 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 226835186  | Title Version 11  | Img Style 12 | 2016-02-16 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 228703248  | Title Version 21  | Img Style 21 | 2016-02-15 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 228703248  | Title Version 22  | Img Style 22 | 2016-02-17 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 228703248  | Title Version 23  | Img Style 21 | 2016-02-16 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 230105831  | Title Version 31  | Img Style 31 | 2016-02-12 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 230105831  | Title Version 32  | Img Style 31 | 2016-02-06 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
```

I am trying to get a query of distinct `listing_id` with a latest used version of `transaction_title` and `image_thumb`. For the above table query output will be:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| listing_id | transaction_title | image_thumb  | sale_date  |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 226835186  | Title Version 11  | Img Style 12 | 2016-02-16 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 228703248  | Title Version 22  | Img Style 22 | 2016-02-17 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| 230105831  | Title Version 31  | Img Style 31 | 2016-02-12 |
+------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
```

I've tried different combinations of `select distinct, num_rows and max()` but can't get the desired result.

Latest I've tried:

```
SELECT
    listing_id,transaction_title,image_thumb,sale_date
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM sales
    ORDER BY sale_date DESC
) AS transaction_title
GROUP BY listing_id
```

Please help!

Comment: What MySQL-Version do you use? and what is your primary key?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel mysql 5.0.11

Comment: Doesn't your query work? I don't see a reason, why it shouldn't - Even thoug i wouldn't do it like that.

Comment: @Acidon Look at my answer, it should work for you.

Comment: Looks like OP already had a working query but wanted the result to be ordered by sale_date again. One more line at the end (`ORDER BY sale_date DESC;`) would fix his problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number base approach with data sorted descending first on listing_id and sale_date and then picking the rows with row_number 1. This will give you the required dataset. A query template for this approach is as follows:

```
SELECT  INVW.listing_id, INVW.transaction_title, INVW.image_thumb, INVW.sale_date 
FROM (
    SELECT  listing_id, transaction_title, image_thumb, sale_date
        ,@rank := if(@listing_id = listing_id or listing_id is null, @rank + 1, 1) as row_number 
        ,@listing_id := listing_id as dummy
    FROM <###REPLACE_ME_WITH_TABLE_NAME###>, (select @rank := 0,@listing_id := '') rank
    ORDER BY listing_id,sale_date DESC 
) INVW where INVW.row_number = 1;
```

Comment: Out of all suggested answers, this is the only one that returned the correct results, thank you, Usman!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query to select the max date of each one of them like this:

```
SELECT listing_id,transaction_title,image_thumb,sale_date
FROM sales t
WHERE (listing_id,sale_date) in (select s.listing_id,max(s.sale_date)
                                 from sales s
                                 where t.listing_id = s.listing_id
                                 group by s.listing_id)
```

Comment: What about two sales on same date?

Comment: With the same id? How would that happen? He said he want to the max date, if there are two is the same max date then unless he will tell us which one to take, we cant figure it out on our own. Although I don't think it will happen in this case @PaulSpiegel

Comment: That is why i asked for primary key. And my query would be : select .. where pk = (select pk .. order by .. limit 1)

Comment: Then it's time to add an autoincrement pk :-)

Comment: I will just assume that (listing_id, sale_date) is unique - so your query is correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived table containing maximum dates per `listing_id`. If you `INNER JOIN` to this table you can get the exprected result set:

```
select t1.listing_id, transaction_title, image_thumb, sale_date
from mytable as t1
inner join (
   select listing_id, max(sale_date) max_date
   from mytable
   group by listing_id
) as t2 on t1.listing_id = t2.listing_id and sale_date = max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

just use subquery to get the listing_id and it's max sale_date first and then use it to find out other column

```
select * 
  from table t0 
 where exists
   (select 1 from 
      (select listing_id,max(sale_date) as sale_date 
         from table group by listing_id) t1 
        where t1.listing_id = t0.listing_id and t1.sale_date = t0.sale_date)
```

Comment: The aliases are recognized two levels down?

Answer (score 0):

You can get expected result using correlated subquery.

```
SELECT
    s1.listing_id, s1.transaction_title, s1.image_thumb, s1.sale_date
FROM sales s1
WHERE ( s1.listing_id, s1.transaction_title, s1.image_thumb, s1.sale_date ) IN   
                (SELECT s2.listing_id, s2.transaction_title, s2.image_thumb, s2.sale_date
                 FROM sales s2
                 WHERE s2.listing_id = s1.listing_id
                 ORDER BY s2.sale_date DESC
                 LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: What if the image didn't change and there are two list_id,image the same? see 230105831  in his example

Comment: Different lasting_id will go into different subqueries, since we have filter "WHERE s2.listing_id = s1.listing_id".

Comment: Ok, but lasting_id(230105831) has two records with the same image_thumb , so both of them will be selected.

Comment: From my understanding, only one row should be selected. "| 230105831  | Title Version 32  | Img Style 31 | 2016-02-06 |" When there are two columns, we can't always find a row with both max(c1) and max(c2) and they may at different rows. Therefore, a logic for ORDER BY c1 DESC, c2 DESC is used.

Comment: @Acidon Pls have a try to check if the answer meet your expectation.

Comment: I didn't really read the subquery ... ORDER BY s2.transaction_title DESC is wrong, version 2 is bigger then version 12 in strings, in addition, by his output example you can understand he want the data that appear on the max data, no matter if its an older version or image , so I can tell you now, it doesn't meet his expectation..

Comment: You need to add `transaction_title` in your where clause and subselect: `WHERE ( s1.listing_id, s1.transaction, s1.image_thumb ) IN (SELECT s2.listing_id, s2.transaction, s2.image_thumb ...`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Even then, hypothetical , isn't it possible to have twice the same (id,trans,img) ?

Comment: @sagi It would'nt matter if ordering would be by sale_date.

Comment: Why not? then two records will meet the condition and will be selected.. @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Oh.. you're right. Then it would be same result as your solution :-)

Comment: To prevent selecting duplicates you might also want to use DISTINCT.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I put the s2.sale_date into the ORDER BY s2.sale_date DESC to avoid the duplicate. Just updated. Thanks.

Comment: The order should be **only** by sale_date (see the original query).

Answer (score -1):

Because correlations between max values are not defined, you simply can get MAX values for each column:

```
SELECT
    listing_id,
    MAX(transaction_title) transaction_title,
    MAX(image_thumb) image_thumb,
    MAX(sale_date) sale_date
FROM
    sales
GROUP BY
    listing_id
```

Comment: That will not return what he asked for, he is not selecting the max image_thumb and transaction_title . And even if he did, Version 2 is bigger then Version 11 , so it won't work .

Comment: He is looking for "latest used version of transaction_title and image_thumb". And where we have Version 2?

Comment: "latest used version" is not equal to "highest values"

Comment: So what defines "latest used version" in this data in that case? sale_date or what?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel is right, and he doesn't have version 2, but you now.. its dummy data, so you can assume he will have version 2 with his real data.(It doesn't matter your logic in incorrect)